# Unrecognized Token : "#" C# to SQLITE

Tags: c#, sqlite

***Background + Problem:***

( Begginer here ) I want to populate sqlite db with values from a list I have in my c# code. Here's the sqlite code taken from finisarsqlite website: I modified it a bit by creating my own column names like "seq#" etc.

But I'm getting the following error : ***"unrecognized token #"***

Maybe my syntax is off?

***Code:***

```
             // [snip] - As C# is purely object-oriented the following lines must be put     into a class:

        // We use these three SQLite objects:
        SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
        SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

        // create a new database connection:
        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

        // open the connection:
        sqlite_conn.Open();

        // create a new SQL command:
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

        // Let the SQLiteCommand object know our SQL-Query:
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE table1 (Seq# integer primary key, Field integer primary key, Description integer primary key);";

        // Now lets execute the SQL ;D                                                                                  
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); <<< ---- This is where Error Occurs !

        // Lets insert something into our new table:
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (Seq#, Field, Description) VALUES (list[0], list[1], list[2]);";

        // And execute this again ;D
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        // We are ready, now lets cleanup and close our connection:
        sqlite_conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Try wrapping [ ] around your column names and see if that solves the problem?

Comment: Try adding a @ in front of the `CommandText`

Comment: After fixing first error, next error will be in `"INSERT INTO table1 (Seq#, Field, Description) VALUES (list[0], list[1], list[2]);"`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL, you cannot use `#` in a plain identifier.

What you can use is a quoted identifer.
In SQL, this is done with double quotes (`"Seq#"`).
MySQL uses single quotes (`'Seq#'`) or backticks (`` `Seq#` ``); SQL Server uses brackets (`[Seq#]`); [all these are supported in SQLite for compatibility](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

If you don't want to quote the name whenever it is used, drop the `#`.

Comment: I'd highly suggest not getting in the habit of using special characters like # in variable names, table names, field names etc.

Comment: I'll try implementing these advises when I get time to work on the application again, and will check the right answer - thx!